# Regex to find N characters between underscore and period

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have a filename having numerals like **test_20200331_2020041612345678.csv**.

So I just want to read only first 8 characters from the number between last underscore and .csv using a regex. 
For e.g: From the file name test_20200331_**20200416**12345678.csv --> i want to read only **20200416** using regex.

Regex tried:    `(?<=_)(\d+)(?=\.)`

But it is returning the full number between underscore and period i.e **2020041612345678**

Also, when tried quantifier like **`(?<=_)(\d{8})(?=\.)`** its not matching with any string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?<=_)(\d{8})(?=\.)` does not work because the `(?=\.)` positive lookahead requires the presence of a `.` char **immediately to the right of the current location**, i.e. right after the eigth digit, but there are more digits in between.

You may add `\d*` before `\.` to match any amount of digits after the required 8 digits,  use

```
(?<=_)\d{8}(?=\d*\.)
```

Or, with a capturing group, you do not even need lookarounds (just make sure you access Group 1 when a match is obtained):

```
_(\d{8})\d*\.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XTPw4V/2)

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/0379Qm):

```
import re
s = "test_20200331_2020041612345678.csv"
m = re.search(r"(?<=_)\d{8}(?=\d*\.)", s)
# m = re.search(r"_(\d{8})\d*\.", s) # capturing group approach
if m:
    print(m.group())  # => 20200416
    # print(m.group(1))  # capturing group approach
```

Comment: can you please also explain why (?<=_)(\d{8})(?=\.) did not worked??

Comment: @TusharRastogi Added that explanation.